# How to get a single HTML page accessible from the web -- no cost

Tags: html, web

I need to load one `html` page to the web without any server and without paying for this service.

What are my options?

Comment: For anyone to see by going to the URL (which I assume the url does not matter since you are not going to pay anything)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Dinkypage](http://www.dinkypage.com/), a service that lets you create disposable webpages.

Here's information from [the site's FAQ](http://www.dinkypage.com/#faq):

> **Can I edit my page later?**
>
> You sure can! Simply bookmark page with editor and use it whenever you need to make changes. You can also send yourself an email that will contain link to both page with editor and your page online.
>
> ---
>
> **When does my page expire?**
>
> Pages do not expire and they **will not** be deleted automatically unless they violate the [Terms of Use](http://www.dinkypage.com/#terms).
>
> ---
>
> **Can I use Javascript/Flash on my page?**
>
> Absolutely. You can use pretty much anything (even build small websites!).
>
> ---
>
> **I found a page that violates the Terms of Use. What should I do?**
>
> Please send the page link to support@dinkypage.com with a short explanation and after reviewing, it will be removed if in violation.

Answer (score 3):

Go to dropbox.com and upload the file to the public folder. Once it's there you can just write down the url and then access it without even having to log in to drop box.